# SQL to Linq conversion returning default value in subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a ticketing system that I am trying to get some basic information of the last ticket note added, based on what tickets are still open.

Here are the tables summarized, including extra columns that I'm not querying:

Ticket table

```
TicketId
CustomerId
DateIn
CallNature
OpenClosed
```

TicketDetails table

```
TicketDetailsId
TicketId
TicketNote
DateLogged
```

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT
    t.TicketId,
    t.CustomerId,
    t.DateIn,
    (SELECT TOP 1 td.DateLogged 
     FROM TicketDetails td 
     WHERE td.TicketId = t.TicketId 
     ORDER BY td.DateLogged DESC) DateLogged
FROM 
    Tickets t
WHERE 
    t.OpenClosed = 1
```

Here is my current Linq query:

```
var result = from t in ef.Tickets
  where t.OpenClosed == true
  select new
  {
    TicketId = t.TicketId,
    CustomerId = t.CustomerId,
    DateIn = t.DateIn,
    DateLogged = (from td in ef.TicketDetails
                   where td.TicketId == t.TicketId
                   orderby td.DateLogged descending
                   select td.DateLogged).Take(1)
  };
```

Here is a result sample of the Linq query:

```
TicketId = 11000
CustomerId = 4622
DateIn = 2018-01-25T00:00:00
DateLogged = 0001-01-01T00:00:00
```

should be:

```
TicketId = 11000
CustomerId = 4622
DateIn = 2018-01-25T00:00:00
DateLogged = 2018-12-12T13:32:42
```

I don't have all the fields in the example but they are irrelevant to the question.

When I run the SQL query, the results are as expected.  When I run the Linq query, all fields are populated except for the DateLogged, it keeps returning default value (0001-01-01).

I have confirmed that each Ticket has at least 1 TicketDetail to return.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try `First()` instead of `Take(1)`.  Also make sure that your subquery is actually returning data.

Comment: How many `TicketDetails` records are there for a given `TicketID`?

Comment: Are you including `TicketDetails` ? Can you post lines before `var result`?

Comment: There is at least 1 TicketDetail for any given TicketID.  Trying First() yeilded no results, FirstOrDefault() does same as Take(1).

Comment: @kamalpreet There is nothing before var result (other than a List<TicketResult> that will hold the anonymous type).  The TicketDetails is a subquery of the initial select.

Comment: if `Ticket` entity has navigation property to `TicketDetails`, you can simply do `DateLogged = t.TicketDetails.Select(x => x.DateLogged).Max()`

Comment: Did you try joining these tables and selecting the appropriate fields at the end?

Comment: @kamalpreet Good call on Navigation property, but oddly returns same result. Also tried Take(1).FirstOrDefault().DateLogged same behavior.

Comment: @NthDeveloper I wasn't able to get a good query using JOIN, it's returning all rows from the details table instead of just the last entry

Comment: The code looks correct to me, I would suggest examining the SQL generated - also, your query is incomplete (the anonymous object isn't closed). You could try using LINQPad to run some tests (easier if you are not using EF/EF Core).

Comment: Try SQL profiler to debug further. See what SQL is generated and then you'll be able to quickly tackle the problem

Comment: Ok. I'm way confused now.  So i took the Linq query (result.ToString()) which gives me the raw SQL, pasted that into SSMS and I get the results I need. Not sure why C# is having such a hard time with it.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks, i cleaned up my example ;) I am using EF. This is so bizarre. It works fine in SSMS, and in LinqPad and Linqer. Copy paste. I feel a "did you turn it off and back on again?" coming up next ha.

Comment: Well, `Take(1)` returns an `IEnumerable<>` so unless you expect that, you should be using `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: I think your problem is with linqs deferred execution.  By the time you get to the select new {} you’ve already lost the original context, and that is why you are getting default values because it’s unable to do the join.

Comment: You should try it as a join and not as a sub select.

Comment: @Neil.Work THANKS! Adding a .ToList() at the end was the trick. Unfortunate for the downvote, didn't think this was that terrible a question.

Comment: @Neil.Work I can't seem to wrap my head around the join. All variations I've tried either return 1 result, or all details, and not just the last.  Would really appreciate a sample or link if you have one handy that accomplishes my goal.

Comment: I think this was a reasonable question, I don’t know why people are down voting it.  Maybe it’s more about the framing of the question and not the actual issue you are having.  I’ll try to write up a join example if I get to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution thanks to Neil's reference to deferred execution is:

```
var result = (from t in ef.Tickets
where t.OpenClosed == true
select new {
  TicketId = t.TicketId,
  CustomerId = t.CustomerId,
  DateIn = t.DateIn,
  DateLogged = (from td in ef.TicketDetails
                where td.TicketId == t.TicketId
                orderby td.DateLogged descending
                select td.DateLogged).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

And a link to a post explaining difference between Linq query execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution